# Unable to Pull messagecollector values

Tags: collections, discord.js

I'm currently having issues with iterating through a `MessageCollector` in the `end` event like so:

```
collector.on('end', collected => {
   message.channel.send("Searching... \r\n");
   //  .log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
   //console.log(collected);
   console.log(collected.first(collected.size).content);

});
```

Everything I have attempted is coming up undefined, the actual collection size has no limit due to wanting to log as much information as possible until timeout. However, getting the actual results from this list is proving tricky. I've tried `collected.values()` and such.. All undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collected.first(collected.size).content` is indeed `undefined`, because by putting the collected size as an amount in `collected.first()` you will get an array of [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) and so you will need to iterate on it with a forEach loop for example to get each messages content.

By the way, `collected.first(collected.size)` is useless because you already get all messages in `collected` unless you would like to get an Array from your [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection).. but `Collection.array()` would fit better to get an Array from a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection).

In case you didn't noticed, a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) extends [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

So to iterate on all messages you collected I suggest you to do the following :

```js
collector.on("end", collected => {
    collected.forEach(message => {
        ...
    });
})
```

I hope I helped you well!